# Get milliseconds between two times

Tags: java, date, time

This question has probably been answered before. But here I go.

I have a String object with value "**21:48**" and another String object with value "23:23". **How can I calculate the milliseconds between these two times?**

Comment: On what day?  Leapseconds and daylight savings may make the answer different at different times.

Comment: Probably same day, but the time could be after midnight if you know what I mean?

Comment: What does your `formatTime()` method have to do with your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Java time, you can obtain the total amount of milliseconds between two date-time objects by creating a `Duration` object.

```
Duration duration = // TODO
long millis = duration.toMillis();
```

You did specify `21:48` and `23:23` as `String` input values. You can use the `LocalTime` class to represent this concept of hours, minutes and seconds.

```
LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.parse("21:48");
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse("23:23");

Duration ldd = Duration.between(lt1, lt2);
long millis = duration.toMillis(); // 5700000
```

Please note that this `Duration` only relates to the `LocalTime`. If you want to measure the *real* amount of milliseconds, you have to consider that time-zones may apply daylight saving time.

```
// in Germany, for example, at 2020-10-25 on 03:00 clocks are turned backward 1 hour 
ZoneId berlin = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-24"), lt1);
LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse("2020-10-25"), lt2);

ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt1, berlin);
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt2, berlin);

// does not consider DST (one hour is missing)
Duration d1 = Duration.between(ldt1, ldt2);
long ms1 = d1.toMillis(); // 92100000

// does consider DST (extra hour applied)
Duration d2 = Duration.between(zdt1, zdt2);
long ms2 = d2.toMillis(); // 95700000
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long millis = LocalTime.parse("21:48").until(LocalTime.parse("23:23"), ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
        System.out.println(millis);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5700000
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score -1):

Using [Joda-Time](https://joda.org/joda-time):

```
DateTime zero = new DateTime(time); 
long millis = new org.joda.time.Period(DateTime.now()).toDurationFrom(zero).getMillis();
```

Comment: What is period?

Comment: Where do I fit the two strings from the question in?